# How to get font size from text in python

Tags: python, excel, fonts

Working with Excel sheet. There seems to be a dozen ways to set the font size, but getting it seems to be less common. How would one do it in python?

Comment: Your question is to broad and likely to be closed. When working with spreadsheet data in Python most of the time is it NOT about the presentation of that data, but about the data itself. Are you talking about manipulating Microsoft Office documents, right? What Python library are you using? What code do you have? Does it fail? If it fails what is the error message? On Stack Overflow you should be more specific.

Comment: I am talking about MS Excel yes. The final goal is to manipulate the data to restructure it to csv format, but only way the data is differentiable is by font size. I've tried to use xlrd and openpyxl, but these only seem to offer setting the font size instead of getting it.

Comment: One google away: `cell.font = Font(name='Courier', size=36)` https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html#write-only-mode

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be a way to set the font size instead of getting it.

Answer (score 0):

`cell.font.size`. I have to be able to find out this one for my another question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51362569/9023855